# react developer console not showing up

Tags: reactjs

I have react chrome extension installed and I know its working since it shows up on instagram.com. However, I'm going through the React tutorial (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) and the react tab is not showing up in my console window here is all the code I have:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
    var data = [
      {author: "Derp", text: "this is another comment"},
      {author: "Derp", text: "this is a comment"}
    ];

      var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
              console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
          });
        },
        handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
          $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: comment,
            success: function(data) {
              this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
              console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
          });
        },
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {data: []};
        },
        componentDidMount: function() {
          this.loadCommentsFromServer();
          setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
        }
        render: function() {
          return (
            <div className="commentBox">
              <h1>Comments</h1>
              <CommentList data={this.state.data}/>
              <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit}/>
            </div>
          );
        }
      });

      var CommentList = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
          var comments = this.props.data.map(function (comment){
            return (
              <Comment author={comment.author}>
                {comment.text}
              </Comment>
            )
          })

          return (
            <div className="commentList">
              {comments}
            </div>
          );
        }
      });

      var Comment = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
          return (
            <div className="comment">
              <h2 className="commentAuthor">
                {this.props.author}
              </h2>
              {this.props.children}
            </div>
          );
        }
      })

      var CommentForm = React.createClass({
        handleSubmit: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var author = this.refs.author.getDOMNode().value.trim();
          var text = this.refs.text.getDOMNode().value.trim();
          if(!text || !author) {
            return;
          }
          this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
          this.refs.author.getDOMNode().value = '';
          this.refs.text.getDomNode().value = '';
        },
        render: function() {
          return (
            <div className="commentForm">
              <form className="commentForm">
                <input type="text" placeholder="your name" ref="something"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="say something" ref="someting" />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }
      });

      React.render(
        <CommentBox url="comments.json" pollInterval={2000}/>,
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my console says the following:

```
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: http://fb.me/react-devtools

You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx

Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 41: Unexpected identifier
```

I have a bug in there somewhere, but I'm trying to get the React tab to show up for the time being and not too sure how to do it.

Comment: After `componentDidMount` method in `CommentBox` you forgot to add a comma

Comment: thx, apparently the bug was preventing React extension from loading

Comment: If you have a solution you can write about it in the answer box provided and then accept it. (or delete the question). This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question, which leaves it in the "unanswered" queue for all perpetuity.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue: I installed `React Developer Tools` plugin, but the `React` tab didn't appear.
The solution was simple: I just closed the Chrome tab and opened it again - and it was there.

You can read about other possible reasons on their official GitHub page https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools#user-content-the-react-tab-doesnt-show-up

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because I didn not have global React object, or a global require that is able to require('react') from global scope.
I was able to make the extension work by requiring react in my gulpfile. I'm sure it would work the same in a webpack file:

```
var React = require('react');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an update to the extension.

If you installed the extension but you don't see in console

> **REACT**

It's because they Changed it to **Components and Profiler**.

Tips:
 1. Go to Developer Tools, Click the **Components**.
 2. Click the icon settings(view settings).
 3. Find the icon that says filtered Enabled or Disable it.

Just play with it, it's much better now :)